# Custom ports for dhclient

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, ubuntu-11.04

I'm writing a cut-down DHCP server implementation for a specific use-case. Rather than split off onto a private network for the development I'm running the server on a custom port (11167) and sending to a custom port (11168).

In order to test the system without needing access to the embedded client I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 running in Virtual Box.

I'm wondering how I can get `dhclient` on the Ubuntu box to talk to port 11167 and receive on port 11168.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dhclient(8) man page:

> If the DHCP client should listen and transmit on a port other than the standard (port 68), the -p flag may used.  It should be  followed  by  the
>   udp port number that dhclient should use.  This is mostly useful for debugging purposes.  If a different port is specified for the client to lis-
>   ten on and transmit on, the client will also use a different destination port - one less than the specified port.

(Note this is from the **isc-dhcp-client** package in Debian squeeze. I don't know if your version of Ubuntu ships with a different dhclient package)

Comment: Thanks. Found this just after posting the quesion. Duh! The command: `sudo dhclient -r` releases any current address and stops the client. Then the command: `sudo dhclient -p 11168 -d eth0` starts the client communicating with the server on port 11167 and keeps it in the foreground. Perfect!

Comment: PS. Can't seem to find a way of permanently changing the port using the `dhclient.conf` config file.